# Uploading a Html file and breaking it into events in splunk

Tags: html, splunk

How to upload a HTML file in Splunk and break it into events.

> I see that there is no predefined source type for html in splunk

Answer (score 1):

What are the contents of the html file? You may be better parsing your data in something like python and indexing the output.

What is your use case here?

Comment: I want to upload the html file in splunk for reporting.The html file consists of some text in paragraphs and table with data in rows in table.I want to basically to extract the data in rows in table.

Comment: I agree with Simon Duff.  You can teach Splunk to process HTML, but it likely will index the entire file.  To get just the table rows write a python or shell script to extract the desired parts into a separate file for Splunk to index.